# Cannot hand over fstream from a funcion to another function (C++)

Tags: c++

I cannot hand over my fstream to a function I had created to write text into a textfile.

The fstreams I want to use (for now i only want to use usernameFile):

```
fstream passwordFile;
fstream usernameFile; 
fstream nameFile;
```

the function where I want to use the "fstream":

```
void writer(fstream fileToWrite, string stringToWrite, string fileName)
{
    fileToWrite.open(fileName, ios::app);
    if(fileToWrite.is_open())
    {
        fileToWrite << stringToWrite << endl;
    }
}
```

The function from where i call the "writer"-function to where i need to hand over the "usernameFile" fstream

```
void actionLogin() //loginprocedure
{
    string username;
    string password;

    cout << "Type in your Username" << endl;
    cin >> username;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Type in your Password" << endl;
    cin >> password;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Starting verification" << endl;
    
    reader(usernameFile, username, "UsernameSaveFile");

}
```

[where i want to hand over:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXo6t.png)

[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxNSr.png)

Hope anyone can halp me :)

Answer (score 3):

Your error message is telling you that you cannot copy a `std::fstream` object. To resolve this, you can take it by *reference* in `writer`; this is as simple as adjusting the function to take `fstream &fileToWrite`, i.e.

```cpp
void writer(fstream &fileToWrite, string stringToWrite, string fileName);
```

The same is true of the `reader` method, for the same reasons.

Comment: In fact, all three parameters should be passed by reference (the last two by `const` reference).

Comment: Ooooh ok, thank you! Yeah just niticed, that I copied the code of the wrong function (writer instead of reader ) but works with both ig :)